# Migrate newly added articles using CMigrator

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I have migrated a WordPress site into Joomla using CMigrator component. But after the migration and while working in development server, there are some more articles added to the Production site.

I am stuck at this point now how to migrate those "new" articles and categories now in my Joomla website as I have finished all the work in it. But now I have the updated database of Wordpress site.

I only want to add the newly added articles from the time I have migrated the website.

Please guide me on this on how to proceed

Comment: I have never used CMigrator from Compojoom before, but from the quick glance on their Documentation I can see that process involves importing dumped WP SQL into Joomla. I cannot say for sure, but I am afraid that such a process doesn't allow partial import, or differential import that you need. You should direct your Q to either developer or to their Forum.

Comment: Agree with @Mirko Mikan, I don't beleive you can import differential content from SQL.

Comment: Ok thank you for your responses. Surely I will ask to their official forum or developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the recommendations, I posted the question in the official forum of CMigrator and thankfully I got the solution to it.

Following are the steps which were followed by me:

1. Took the backup of the website
2. Exported the new updated wordpress tables in joomla database
3. Open CMigrator component > configuration wizard > select `no` for `clean migration` option. By doing so, the old articles are not deleted.
4. All the new categories and articles which already existed in my website were now named as `title cmigrator copy1`.
5. This helped me in differentiating the new articles from the existed ones
6. Manually deleted all the `cmigrator copy` articles and categories.
7. Manually moved the new articles to the old categories.
8. My website now has all the updated articles from the Wordpress site.

**For more details refer here:** https://compojoom.com/forum/pre-sales-questions/21209-partial-migration-from-wordpress

Though this process was a little time taking but was worth it.

Comment: Thank you @Ruchika for this great mini-guide. It's good to know that, in case we need to use that process in the future...

Comment: yes @MirkoMikan I am glad to help. Because such a situation can arrive to any of us any time. Because clients can do anything ;) and we have to be prepared for it

Comment: Yes @Ruchika, you are right. We might have such a job of converting WP to Joomla any day. Upwork is full of them...